# Disable click event on HTML table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to disable click on a table cell when the cell is empty or has value as zero.
I have a table in which when i click on a particular cell certain operations are performed. But I want the click event not to work when the table has cell value 0 or empty cell

```
$('#tablename').off('click','td').on('click', 'td', function(e) { 
    var column = e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex];
    var row = this.parentNode.cells[1]; 

    if ($(row).text().trim() == "")
    {
        row = this.parentNode.cells[0]; 
    }

    var rowvalue = $(row).text();
    var columnvalue = $(column).text();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: it depends on how the click event is handled, please show us your code...

Comment: Post code example. Only then we will be able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var v = $(this).html();
   if( $.trim(v) != '0' && v != '' ){
      // your code
   }
});
```

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping all dom elements with zero or empty string values, then disable their default clicking functions:

```
var duds = $('td').map(function () {
    if ($(this).html() == 0 || $(this).html() == "") {
        return $(this);
    }
});

duds.onclick(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, modify it according to your code:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
        <td>Content <input type="text" class="hidden"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.visible {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var tds = $('td');

tds.click(function(){
   var thisTable = $(this).html();
   if( thisTable == '0' || thisTable  == '' ){

   var allInputs = tds.find('input');
    allInputs.removeClass('visible');
    allInputs.addClass('hidden');
}
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I wont prefer to give you the whole solution but the just a hint. You should use following line of code

```
<td onclick="return false;">Content</td>
```

This is inline event handling - you can always use jquery to avoid inline event handling - this would also be a good homework for you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this css property

```
pointer-events: none;
```

[and you can refer more in this link:](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50490577.html)